# I ran a script using nohup which calls 3 subscripts inside

Tags: unix

`nohup ksh mail_failures.ksh >temp.out &`
As this script calls another 3 scripts and it runs forever..I couldn't kill this job..I tried below
`ps -ef | grep nohup`
This command giving only one output with pid..after I killed that and 
It showing with the different PID
How can I resolve this?

Comment: sounds like a) the parent script (`mail_failures.ksh`) has a looping construct that calls (at least) one of the other 3 (child) scripts, b) you killed the pid of one of the child scripts (which doesn't kill the parent's looping construct) so 3) the parent looped around and called the child script again; have you tried killing the pid of the parent script first and then (if necessary) kill the pid of the child script?

Comment: How can I get the pid of parent process?

Comment: `ps -ef` should be displaying 2x process IDs ... `PID` and `PPID` (parent of PID); instead of looking for `nohup`, try looking for `mail_failures.ksh` and/or the other scripts

Answer (score 0):

How can we get the pid of parent?
Everytime I do `ps -ef |grep nohup` I'm getting only one output..and if I try to kill it again it's saying it coming with a different PID..?